# Wordpress Listify theme - Contact Form 7 sending to wrong e-mail address

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, email

So we purchased a theme from Themeforest. Listify theme. Of course after launching and handing the site over to the client, problems start to arise.

https://bamasbestbuilders.com/listing/farmco-builders-of-alabama-llc/
There is a feature within the site for "Claiming a Listing".

The Claim Listing link opens a popup form. The form is being used from Contact Form 7. So naturally, the form should be sent to the e-mail address provided within the CF7 plugin, but instead goes to the e-mail address associated with the listing, which is the Listing Owner contact email.

I've tried using the plugin Postman SMTP, but wasn't much of a help even after connecting to gmail API.

Anyone have any suggestions on what is happening? I've also tried Deactivating CF7 plugin, deleting its files and data, and reinstalled.... No luck.